# How can I insert a row only if it does't already exist?

Tags: postgresql

I'm trying to insert a row but only if it is not already present in the table. At the moment I'm using code similar to the following:

```
insert into mentions (project_id, id, data_source, channel)
  select 3, '123456789', 'example.com', 'twitter'
  where not exists
    (select 1 as "one" from mentions where (project_id = 3 and id = '123456789'))
returning reach;
```

But I sometimes see it fail with the following error in the logs

> ERROR:  duplicate key value violates unique constraint "mentions_pkey"
>
> DETAIL:  Key (project_id, id)=(3, 123456789) already exists.

and the constraint is defined as

```
Index "public.mentions_pkey"
┌────────────┬─────────┬────────────┐
│  Column    │  Type   │ Definition │
├────────────┼─────────┼────────────┤
│ project_id │ integer │ project_id │
│ id         │ text    │ id         │
└────────────┴─────────┴────────────┘
primary key, btree, for table "public.mentions"
```

Since I'm only inserting when the exists clause is false, I don't understand how this can ever fail with a constraint violation.

Could it be a concurrency issue? I was under the assumption that individual statements are atomic but maybe this isn't the case?

I know that once 9.5 ships I can use `ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING`, but I'm running 9.4 at the moment.

Comment: That question was asked when most recent version of Postgresql hadn't on conflict clause. Notice that op specified version after the first two questions were post, too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. handle errors in stored procedure

```sql
  CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION some_insert() RETURNS VOID AS
  $$BEGIN
    BEGIN
      insert into mentions (project_id, id, data_source, channel)
            select 3, '123456789', 'example.com', 'twitter';
      RETURN;
    EXCEPTION WHEN unique_violation THEN
      -- do nothing
    END;
  END;$$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

2. lock table

```sql
BEGIN;
LOCK TABLE mentions IN SHARE ROW EXCLUSIVE MODE;
INSERT INTO mentions (project_id, id, data_source, channel)
    SELECT 3, '123456789', 'example.com', 'twitter'
    WHERE NOT EXISTS
        (SELECT 1 AS "one" FROM mentions WHERE (project_id = 3 AND id = '123456789'))
COMMIT;
```

3. handle errors on postgres' client side

Comment: Yeah, I think that I'm going to have to go the stored procedure version, was hoping to avoid that :-(

Answer (score 1):

use `ON CONFLICT` optional clause on insert:

```
insert into mentions  (project_id, id, data_source, channel)
  values (3, '123456789', 'example.com', 'twitter')
  ON CONFLICT (project_id, id) DO NOTHING;
```

look: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/sql-insert.html#SQL-ON-CONFLICT

Comment: 9.5 hasn't been released yet, it's still in beta.